# Railsで、パーシャルの中に個別のviewの内容を表示したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails

以下のようなコードで、いろんなコントローラ共通のviewをパーシャルとして切り出し、個別の部分をindexに書く、ということをしたいです。
この個別の部分は実際にはコードが長くなるので、変数で渡すことは考えておりません。
以下のようにすると、aaaaaaは表示されますが、yieldが動かず、bbbbbが表示されません。
どうすれば良いでしょうか。

```
<!-- /shared/_index.html.erb -->
<div class="contents">
    aaaaaa
    <% yield %>
</div>

<!-- index.html.erb -->
<%= render :layout => "shared/index" do%>
    bbbbb
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<% yield %>
```

じゃなくて

```
<%= yield %>
```

じゃないでしょうか？